# Previous Log Deleted /var/log/secure

Tags: centos, log-files

When I checked /var/log/secure, only logs for current date was present. Why logs for previous date is not present? Any reason on this?

thanks

Comment: Are there other files in there like secure.1.gz?

Comment: I saw the following files secure-20150103, secure-20150104, secure-20150111.

Comment: That's them. `logrotate` is responsible for rotating the logs (how novel) each day.

Comment: ok... I got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's logrotate keeping the logs clean and rotating them each day. It can be configured based on your own needs or disabled altogether.